# Split file using shell based on column value

Tags: bash, shell, split

I have a table which has 2 columns - Person Number and Value. I need to split file with chunk size 12. (Each file having 12 rows)

Input Table

```
100 aewvc
100 bsv
100 fsv
100 r3r
100 sac
100 fwe
100 cre
100 cr3
100 vrev
101 dvs
101 we
101 rever
101 fwcw
101 fcw
101 fwcw
101 fwe
102 rever
103 fwcw
103 fcw
103 fwcw
103 fwe
```

If I use rank function in oracle sql , I can split it in 2 files but person 101 will get splitted in 2 files. I want all rows of a person in single file (First or second doesn't matter).

I have billions of records with multiple columns so Oracle SQL Approach is taking too much time. Any solution using shell script where basic split can be done using sql and later with shell we can make sure to distribute 101 in file1 or file2?

Current output from SQL

### File 1

```
100 aewvc
100 bsv
100 fsv
100 r3r
100 sac
100 fwe
100 cre
100 cr3
100 vrev
101 dvs
```

### File 2

```
101 we
101 rever
101 fwcw
101 fcw
101 fwcw
101 fwe
102 rever
103 fwcw
103 fcw
103 fwcw
103 fwe
```

Desired Output from shell

### File 1

```
100 aewvc
100 bsv
100 fsv
100 r3r
100 sac
100 fwe
100 cre
100 cr3
100 vrev
101 dvs
101 we
101 rever
101 fwcw
101 fcw
101 fwcw
101 fwe
```

### File 2

```
102 rever
103 fwcw
103 fcw
103 fwcw
103 fwe
```

Thanks in advance!!!
Bhushan

Comment: the requirement isn't clear to me... You just want two files, only to keep the same rank not being split? Do you have requirements how big (how many rows) max. in each file?

Comment: You state that you want to split the file with "Each file having 12 rows".  Then you provide sample output in which the two output files have 16 and 5 rows, respectively.  This is a unclear.

Comment: Sorry guyz if I confused on requirement. In Actual data , I will have billions of records with 25 columns. Say I take chunk factor as 100k and total rows are 550k then finally I need 6 files. Next I need to make sure that rows having same Person number are not getting split in multiple files so I need a way to rearrange my files. Ultimately I should have 6 files and File 1 , 2 , 3... need not to have exactly 100k records , it can have 100005 rows.

Comment: That sounds like [Knapsack problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem).

Comment: you said you need to split into files having 12 rows but in desired output file1 as more than 12 rows